# java utf-8 file reading

Tags: java

I am trying to read a UTF-8 encoded file as follows-

```
import java.io.*;

class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("temp.txt"), "UTF-8"));
        String line;
        line = br.readLine();
        line = line.trim();
        boolean val1 = line.length() != 0;
        boolean val2 = !line.startsWith("//");
        System.out.println(val1 + " " + val2);
        br.close();
    }
}
```

File temp.txt contains first line as-

```
//,<verb>,<verb>
```

So, the output should be

```
true false
```

But I get output as

```
true true
```

Can somebody tell me how to fix this?

Comment: I ran that code and got `true false` as expected. Open your `temp.txt` in a text editor and make sure that you don't have any characters in front of the `//`.

Comment: what happens if you output the contents of line, just before you create your booleans?

Comment: The file might have been saved in ascii encoding. Please save the file in utf-8 encoding and then try. Then it gives the wrong output.

Comment: Actually, the file ``temp.txt`` was not written by me. When I saw in file there were no characters before `//` and also when I printed the line I got the line as `//,<verb>,<verb>`. But I deleted the first line and typed it again and now it is giving correct output. Thanks @maba.

Comment: I put my comment in an answer that you can accept.

Comment: +1. Didn't know about BOM before this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your temp.txt in a text editor and make sure that you don't have any characters in front of the `//`.

Comment: It worked. I should have tried that before. But I had opened the file in gedit and checked. There was no character before ``//``. I had also printed the ``line`` variable. That was also not showing any character before ``\\``. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a [BOM (Byte Order Marker)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the file.

These BOM bytes of UTF-8 are: 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF. They are just the first 3 bytes in the file added by text editor when saving as UTF-8. Possibly your text editor should have option to save UTF-8 text without BOM.

Comment: yeah, i'm thinking of the same

Comment: Notepad++ has 1 option to save utf8 file without BOM, but i don't know if the text editor of asker allows that

Comment: I didn't know about BOM. But yes, I think it was present in the beginning of the file. I deleted the first line and rewrote it. Now I am getting correct output. Thanks for the help.